# What does "Defining" a maximum or minimum mean in an order statistics problem?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, terminology, uniform-distribution, order-statistics

I would like to understand what does this problem mean by "defining" a random variable. I know that **$W$** represents the maximum of the order statistics **$X_1$**, **$X_2$**, **$X_3$**, and that **$Z$** represents their minimum.

1.But what does "defining" these variables mean in this context?

2.Does  it mean calculating their pdf and their distribution function?

3.If so, how? What would be the definition of the desity range function?

**I'd appreciate a lot any help  or guidance on  solving it, thanks!**

> Let **$X_1$**, **$X_2$**, **$X_3$** be independent random  variables with an uniform distribution **$\mathcal{U}(0,1)$**.
>
> 1. Define **$W=\max(X_1,X_2,X_3)$** and **$Z=\min(X_1,X_2,X_3)$**.
> 2. Find the **density range function** $R=W-Z$.

Comment: 'Define' is same as 'Let'. You are not asked to do anything in 1). The question you have to answer is in 2).

Comment: Answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2830378/321264) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/33767/321264) for instance.